# How to find the "center" of a subset of vertices in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have an undirected, positive-weighted, connected graph with vertices `V` and edges `E`. I also have a subset `S` of vertices. Right now `V` contains about 22000 vertices and `E` about 23000 edges, but these are expected to go up to about a million for larger inputs. `S`, on the other hand, will usually contain fewer than 1000 vertices, and they are relatively close together in the graph.

I want to find the "center" of `S`, meaning a vertex `c` in `V` from which the distance to the furthest vertex in `S` is as small as possible. It's like the [graph center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_center) but only for a subset of vertices. [Edit:] It's also a [1-center problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-center_problem) on a graph; the more general *k*-center problem is NP-hard but this one is probably easier.

Is there an algorithm to find this center efficiently? Ideally, the performance would only depend on `S` and its surroundings, and not on the entire graph.

I've thought about starting a breadth-first search from all vertices `s_i` in `S` simultaneously, stopping when a vertex `v_i` has been encountered by all `s_i`, but this is not overly efficient. It's probably feasible in this case, but it feels like there might be a better way.

Comment: Might be even worse than *O(|S|²)* since your breadth-first searches might have to go through vertices from *V \ S*.

Comment: You might find more insightful answers on [the computer science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You say the vertices of *S* "are relatively close together in the graph". Do you have an easy way to generate a subgraph that contains the subgraph induced by *S* as well as all "potentially useful" nodes and edges from the big graph?

Comment: @Stef Probably yes. It's a road network so I can take a bounding box.

Comment: The strategy you articulated will take O(|S| * |E|) time, not O(|S|^2) time: each breadth-first search takes O(|V|+|E|)=O(|E|) time, and you do |S| of them.  Early stopping does not change the asymptotic worst-case running time.

Comment: @D.W. Quite true, but let's assume that the number of edges we would traverse with early stopping is also O(|S|). I know it's a bit handwavy, but I'm a software engineer with a practical problem to solve, not a computer scientist with a paper to write ;)

Comment: I can understand caring more about practical performance than asymptotic worst-case running time.  In that case I would recommend you remove the claim about O(|S|^2) time from your post.  I am responding to that specific claim.  If you don't want worst-case analysis then I suspect you'll have to decide what type of analysis you do want and what assumptions can be made and how you will evaluate answers.

Comment: Given that your parallel Dijkstra approach might be fast enough, do you have any interest in approximations?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, I do. Right now I'm using the vertex that is closest to the center of a circumcircle of all points (it's a spatial network as you might have guessed), but this completely ignores the graph structure.

Comment: Since you have a spatial embedding for the nodes of your graph, you may want to look for the distances between nodes of `S` and nodes of the convex hull of `S`. No guarantee on the optimality or on worst case complexity, but in practice it may work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea how to analyze this algorithm and no citation, but it seems like it might work.

1. Choose a starting center. Your current approximation should work well for this.
2. Compute a shortest path tree to S from the current center.
3. Prune the tree so that all leaves belong to S and compute its center.
4. If this center is better than the root, go back to Step 2.

The two formal properties I can really declare about this algorithm are that it always terminates and that it never does worse than the starting center (because if the center of the tree is not the root, then it must be a better center than the root, because the missing edges can improve it but not the root).

To compute the center of a tree efficiently, label each node with the maximum distance to the root over all of its descendants (in linear time by visiting the nodes in post order). Then descend in the tree via the child with the maximum label as long as it improves the radius. Everything in the child's subtree will get closer by the length of the child's parent edge; everything else will get further by the same amount.

Comment: Nice and simple, and quite efficient too. It can't get worse than quadratic in the number of edges: this would happen if each vertex is tested as a potential center, but I find it hard to imagine such a situation. I can imagine (but haven't tried to come up with an example) that it can get stuck in a local minimum, but I don't think I need to worry about that in my case.

Comment: I haven't had time to test this yet, but I'll accept it for now because it is simplest and should get the job done. I'll update once I've tried this approach.

Comment: Turns out I placed the check mark correctly. This algorithm outperforms [your other suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65050591/14637) in terms of runtime, even if I set _k_ as low as 3 in the other one. In terms of output quality, I need to set _k_ = 36 to get a better result from the other algorithm, and at that point it takes over 10 times as long to run.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the update. That's not terribly surprising to me, since the point of the other one is the worst-case guarantee, but typically the input data is very far from adversarial.

Comment: FWIW this one converges in at most 5 steps on my input, usually fewer.

Comment: While I have your attention... I used a different algorithm for finding the center of the tree, but yours sounds nicer. Could you clarify the "as long as it improves the radius" -- I assume you mean eccentricity since we don't know the radius a priori? The eccentricity  e(r) of the root r is equal to its height, h(r). But when we descend into a child c along an edge of length L (where L is maximum among its siblings), how exactly do we compute e(c)?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I meant eccentricity. As mentioned, we compute the height of each subtree initially. Then as we descend, we have the current candidate center v and the maximum distance from v to a node that isn't in v's subtree (initially zero). The eccentricity of v is the max of v's height and the max non-subtree. Once we've identified the child w of v with the greatest height, we update the max non-subtree in two steps. First, for each child x of v where x ≠ w, we update the max non-subtree as max(max non-subtree, length(vx) + height(x)). Then we increase the max non-subtree by length(vw).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approximation algorithm that should offer a decent time-quality trade-off curve. The first part is due to Teofilo F. Gonzalez (Clustering to minimize the maximum intercluster distance, 1985), but I can't find a citation for the second offhand, probably because it's too thin to be a main result.

Let k be the number of times you're willing to run Dijkstra's algorithm (truncated after it reaches all of S, as you suggest). Gonzalez's algorithm runs Dijkstra k − 1 times to partition the terminals S into k clusters so as to 2-approximately minimize the maximum cluster radius. Conveniently, it produces as a byproduct k well-separated centers C and shortest path trees for k − 1 of them. We run Dijkstra one more time and then choose the optimum 1-center with respect to C. This center satisfies

```
approximate objective ≤ optimal objective + maximum cluster radius.
```

It's a little tricky to quantify an approximation factor here in terms of k. The key is bounded doubling dimension, which I'll illustrate by assuming Euclidean distances for a moment. Suppose that we're trying to find the 1-center of a disk of radius 1. The optimum is the center of the disk. How many disjoint radius-r balls centered inside the disk can there be? Their area is contained inside a disk of radius (1+r), which has area π(1+r)², so at most (π(1+r)²)/πr² = (1/r + 1)². The maximum cluster radius will be 2r, or in terms of k, on the order of 4/√k times as large as the optimal objective, so k = 100 will give you a solution within about 20% of optimal. Doubling dimension basically uses this argument as a definition.

For reference, Gonzalez's algorithm is

1. Choose any point in S.
2. Repeat k − 1 times: run Dijkstra from the most recently chosen point, choose the next point in S to maximize the minimum distance to all previously chosen points.

Then we run Dijkstra from the most recently chosen point one more time and then select the optimal 1-center for the chosen points.

Answer (score 0):

**An idea:**

Lets get rid of all the nodes that are not in S in a way that keeps the distances of the other nodes intact. How to do that:

- For every node that is not in S, remove the node and replace it with an edge that connects every two of its neighbors. If such an edge is shorter than an edge already connecting these nodes, replace it. **Note** that this should be reasonable as you mentioned approximately same number of edges as nodes.
- This should not break anything, as it keeps the minimal distance between each two nodes the same by connecting them with new edges. It just removes some of the nodes.
- Start from the nodes with lowest degrees: leaves can be cut immediately(unless in S), nodes with deg 2 will be replaced with a single edge(technically a K2). Any node with deg > 2 will be replaced by K(neighbors). Fortunately the average degree in your graph doesn't seem to be that large as you mentioned that you have similar number of nodes and edges.
- Deconstructing of a worst case, which is a full graph would take |V| * |E|(each node has all the edges that you need to replace, each time you are replacing a node you are updating a rest of the graph and all the edges).  Your case should be much cheaper since your graph has only ~|V| edges, so you most likely won't get to the full |V|^|E| (|V|^3) until much further down the line, when the count becomes manageable. You will also want to keep the nodes sorted through the way, so there will probably be some LOG(|V|) upkeep included - the goal is to wait with merging of the complete graphs until you have as little nodes remaining as possible.

After this trimming is done, just find the center with any reasonable algorithm since you will only have the nodes from |S| remaining and |S| is much smaller than |V|.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This approach doesn't really work for me for two reasons: 1. due to "for every node that is not in S", the performance depends on the total number of vertices (which is much larger than |S|), 2. it assumes that the sought center is actually a member of S.

Comment: Ah, I somehow missed the fact that the center needs not be within the S.  My interpretation was that you are looking for a node within S while taking into account the other nodes for the purpose of possibly shortening the path. So my solution is unusable then ^^. However as for using all the other vertices - other do that too since they search through the graph as far as I could see.

Comment: They can stop searching as soon as all vertices in S have been reached. This shortens the search because the vertices in S are relatively close together.

Comment: In that case take convex envelope around your nodes and search only within? This could cut down the number of nodes in question significantly.